# Task names on the right side of pgfgantt chart, possible?

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to do Gantt chart in Latex thus I'm studying http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf, where I see

[image]

Is it possible to have the task names on the right side? Like this:

[image]

And to have names aligned to the left side will be nice.

Here is the code to generate the first chart:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}

    \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\

    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}

\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

If I do `\begin{ganttchart}[group label node/.append style={anchor=west}]{1}{12}` then I get (but I want that text all the way on the right side):

[image]

Comment: Please add a MWE taken from your linked source.

Comment: MWE from the linked pgfgantt doc is there, anything else I can provide?

Comment: This should be enough. I won't be able to help you, but now that the MWE is provided, you should see an answer quite soon.

Comment: Already helped!

Comment: I had a quick glance at your doc. Maybe playing with `group label node` anchor would help?

Comment: I tried something, see there, not exacly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with setting the anchor to `west`. Additionally, the horizontal (x axis) position of the node needs to be shifted from 0 to [width of the chart]. For this you need to change the code of `pgfgantt.sty`, which you can do on the fly with the `xpatch` package.

Borrowing code from the `\ganttnewline` command (around line 400) the width of the chart is defined as `\gtt@chartwidth * \ganttvalueof{x unit}`. The label nodes are drawn (around line 960) using the coordinates `(0, \y@mid pt)`. When this line is patched, the position of the labels change.

Note that `pgfgantt` defines different styles for bar labels, group labels and milestone labels, so all three need to be defined explicitly (I could not find a single setting for all line labels).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\gtt@chartelement}{\node at (0, \y@mid pt)}{\node at (\gtt@chartwidth * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@mid pt)}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[bar label node/.append style={anchor=west},group label node/.append style={anchor=west},milestone label node/.append style={anchor=west}]{1}{12}

    \gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\

    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7} \ganttnewline
    \ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}

\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to have an option on `pgfgantt` to do this in one shot.

Comment: @KcFnMi you could try to send a feature request to the package maintainer Wolfgang Skala, his e-mail address is listed in the `pgfgantt` manual.